# Change group of characters in a String

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have this String : str = '236112456'

I want to change '236' with something else, and if a character is alone, change by another thing.

i tried something like that :

```
 var result = 
    str.replaceAll('236', '236.jpg')
    .replaceAll('1', '1.jpg')
    .replaceAll('2', '2.jpg')
    .replaceAll...
```

but it won't take 236 and only change individual letters...

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

[edit] - Mistakes in the code example

Comment: you don't have `'236'` in the string ...

Comment: Also, you can't write str.replaceAll() in chain like you did... You should write str.replaceAll().replaceAll().replaceAll()...

Comment: woops, Indeed I managed to make a mistake in the example.

Comment: Hi, just if you replace `236` as first element then `2` will replace `[2]36`, i did understand you question you need to check before replacing because in all cases each `replaceAll` iteration will override the last one,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
Please use regex expression instead of '23' string.

```
str = '236112456';
var result = str.replaceAll(/236/gi, '236.jpg').replaceAll(/1/gi, '1.jpg');
...
```

The result is `"236.jpg1.jpg1.jpg2456"`. Is this not what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've just tried but that doesn't seems to work :/

Comment: I just updated my answer in detail. Check the result if that is what you are going to do.

Comment: I tried again but nope, it change each letters, but not the entire group. 
For the moment I changed the name of the jpg to not match any numbers, so for the moment it's ok ^^
I'm still thinking on a proper way to do it :)